# Region of double integral, absolute value of x + absolute value of y less than or equal than 1 ??

Tags: integration

I have to calculate a double integral of the function 
\begin{equation*}
\int\int e^{x+y}dxdy
\end{equation*}
over the region given by the inequality
\begin{equation*}
\vert x \vert + \vert y \vert \leq 1.
\end{equation*}

My question is: what does this region mean? i tried to draw pictures and stuff and tried other things too, but i dont really understand what the region is.

I also have to make use of a change of variables

Comment: The region will be the rombus with vertex at $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(-1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to figure out the region in a methodical way so you will know how to do the next one like this:

The expression $\lvert x\rvert$ comes out very simple if $x \geq 0$: it's just $x.$
We also get a simple answer if $x \leq 0$: then it's just $-x.$

The expression $\lvert y\vert$ simplifies in a similar way.

So to deal with two absolute values like this, first ask the question:
what if the things inside both absolute values don't change sign?

This occurs exactly when $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$. In that case the main inequality simplifies very nicely to $$x + y \leq 1.$$ That would give you half the plane, except that you have to remember this was only for the case $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$.
So we just get the region that satisfies all three of those inequalities.
This is a triangle in the first quadrant.

Next ask, what happens if the thing inside the first absolute value changes sign, but the second one doesn't?

This occurs when $x < 0$ and $y \geq 0,$ and when you apply this case to 
$\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert \leq 1$ it works out to
$$ -x + y \leq 1. $$
Once again you have to remember that this only applies under the other conditions you supposed, $x < 0$ and $y \geq 0,$ so it ends up being another triangle, this time in the second quadrant.

There are two more cases (the occur when the $y$ part changes sign). These give you two more triangles.

If you plot everything on one graph, you should find out that the triangles are adjacent to each other, so instead of four separate triangles you can look at the region as one connected region. It happens to be a square at a $45$-degree angle to the axes.

If you're very clever, you might realize you can combine some of your cases to get just two inequalities without absolute values. These are shown in another answer.
And either that fact or realizing that you are looking at a region that is actually square, you might think of the change of variables suggested in that answer.
But even if that does not occur to you, you can still integrate over the region,
but using at least two integrals to do it without introducing absolute values again.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $|x|+|y| \leq 1$ can be written as
$$
-1 \leq x+y \leq 1, \quad -1\leq x-y \leq 1,
$$

which motivates the change of variables $u=x+y, v = x-y$. The integral in the new variables will have constant integration limits.

$$
\iint_A e^{x+y} dx dy = \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \frac 12 e^u du dv = \int_{-1}^1e^u du = e - e^{-1}. 
 $$

note: the $\frac 12$ factor comes from the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of the the variable transformation.